# How to update data without possible duplication of id?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am updating a data from database in c# winform. When I update, i don't want it to update if there are same IDnum inside my data. I have a problem doing my bool method.

```
    public bool ExistsKey(string keyField, string table, string value, SqlConnection con){      
    try {
    if(con.State != ConnectionState.Open) con.Open();
    using(SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(
            string.Format("IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE {1}='{2}') SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0", 
                         table, keyField, value), con){
 var result = com.ExecuteScalar();
 return result != null && (int)result == 1;
     }
     } catch {
return false;
     }
     finally {
          con.Close();
     }      
     }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (ExistsKey("idnum", "TableVotersInfo", _idnum.ToString(), sc))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ID number already exist!");
            FAddVoters._cleardata = "0";
            FAddVoters._checkID = checkID;
        }
        else
        {
            if (sc.State != ConnectionState.Open) sc.Open();
            try
            {
                using (cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE TableVotersInfo SET Education=@ed, idnum=@idnum, FirstName=@firstname, MiddleName=@middlename, LastName=@lastname, SchoolYear=@schoolyear, ControlNum=@controlnum WHERE id=@id
                                        SELECT @ed, @idnum, @firstname, @middlename, @lastname, @schoolyear, @controlnum
                                        WHERE @id NOT IN (SELECT idNum FROM TableVotersInfo);", sc))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", _id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ed", _ed);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idnum", _idnum);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", _firstname);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middlename", _middlename);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", _lastname);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@schoolyear", _schoolyear);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@controlnum", _controlnum);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();// <-- this is what you want
                    MessageBox.Show("Data Successfully Updated!");
                    FAddVoters._cleardata = cleardata;
                    FAddVoters._checkID = "0";
                }
            } 
            catch (SqlException ex) 
            {
                if(ex.Number == 2627)//duplicated primary key 
                {
                   MessageBox.Show("ID number already exist!");
                   FAddVoters._cleardata = "0";
                   FAddVoters._checkID = checkID;
                } else 
                {
                   MessageBox.Show("There was some error while attempting to update!\nTry again later.");
                }
            }
            finally 
            {
                sc.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

what am i doing wrong here? The problem is in my `bool`.

**SOME ERROR LIKE**

`var result = com.ExecuteScalar();` = 'Invalid initializer member declarator.'

My **Table**

[image: my table]
<sub>(source: [akamaihd.net](https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/1383507_313879078755024_1274582164_n.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you look closely at your code:

```
using(SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(
        string.Format("IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE {1}='{2}') SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0", 
                     table, keyField, value), con){
```

There is a bracket missing after *"con)"* causing the compiler to think that the rest is part of your SqlCommand construct intializer. If you put in the missing bracket all will be ok :)

```
using(SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(
        string.Format("IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE {1}='{2}') SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0", 
                     table, keyField, value), con)) {
```

Comment: Thanks, i did not see that.. Now my problem is if I update all data from a single user except for the idnum, it always shows that id number already exist? what will i do to retain the idnumber?

Comment: I think your approach is not correct for what you want to achieve. What is the use case? Do you want to update a user if already exists based on idNumber and then only update the other fields (ignoring the idNumber field)? If user doesn't exist do an insert?

Comment: yes, I want it to insert the data if the ID number does not exist in the database. But if I update a specific row and does not change the IDnumber, it still goes "ID number already exist!".

Comment: Basically the code is doing exactly that. You are always checking if idNumber exist and if so you are not performing any update. You should rather specify the logic as follow: 
if (ExistsKey("idnum", "TableVotersInfo", _idnum.ToString(), sc)) PerformUpdate(); else PerformInsert();

Answer (score 0):

since id column is `int` you don't need single qoutes. try with below

`"IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE {1}={2}) SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0"`

code :

```
using(SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(
            string.Format("IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE {1}={2}) SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0", 
                         table, keyField, value), con))
{
    var result = com.ExecuteScalar();
    return result != null && (int)result == 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Now my problem is if I update all data from a single user except for the idnum, it always shows that id number already exist? what will i do to retain the idnumber?